# How to remove Price from Product Category page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove Price from this category page of woocommerce.

[image]

I found the single page price code, which is: `woocommerce\templates\single-product\price.php`

But I can't find the Woocommmerce category pages codes.

I have to remove this price section and add button, which on click will redirect to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File path

```
woocommerce\templates\loop\price.php
```

Remove price code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove either through css or woocommerce snippet as well.

`ul.products li.product span.price{
   display : none !important;
 }`

more details you can check on http://best-php-tutorials.com/hide-prices-from-shop-product-archive-pages-woocommerce/